# How to decide which link is clicked from list item using javascript?

Tags: javascript, list-item

I have inserted an image (with `<a>` tag) like "Add to cart" before the title of list item using SP Designer. Now I want to check that which item's link is clicked using java script. How to do that?

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                             
function Clicked()                          
{                                   
     alert("You have clicked link");
     return false;
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="return Clicked();" title="Add item to cart"><img alt="Add to cart" src="file:///C:/Users/Kalpesh.Vaghela/Desktop/add-to-cart-web-button-9227672.jpg"></img></a>
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure `return Clicked` is the optimal use in the `onclick` event? I advice you to use `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Clicked()">` instead as it makes `return` redundant/unneeded.

Comment: I corrected my code sir, @DanielZiga

Comment: Is there any way to decide which link is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `function Clicked()` to have a parameter.

```
function Clicked(elem) { 
    alert(elem.length); // This is just to alert something
}
```

Then in your click event on the `<a>` tag, add the argument `this` in `Clicked()`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Clicked(this);" title="Add item to card">...</a>
```

The `Clicked` function should now alert the `length` of the clicked `<a>` tag.

**Update**
Since the `<a>` tag is located within XSL and you want to know which item is being clicked, you can create an XSL variable

```
<xsl:variable name="ItemName" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
```

You can now use this XLS variables value in your javascript as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Clicked(value) { 
    alert(value);
}
</script>
<xsl:variable name="ItemName" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Clicked({$ItemName});" title="Add item to card">...</a>
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
```

Change the XML path in the `select` property out with the one you want and that will be alerted by your javascript.

This is just a proof of concept. You'll have to make the  rest of the logic yourself.

Comment: Output comes as "undefined"

Comment: @users1100 Try just alerting `elem` or alert `elem === "undefined"` <- if this returns false it means you have a valid object and can continue from there.

Comment: Plz have a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/ZfgWlf8.png) I want the name of item when user clicks on the green button left side of name. @DanielZiga

Comment: Provide some suggestion or reference.

Comment: @users1100 Check my update.

Comment: I tried your code, but it gives error, with correlation ID..

Comment: @users1100 What does the error corresponding to that correlation ID say? Check the ULS log

Comment: I am not finding the correlation ID in the log file, just checking it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10627/discussion-between-users1100-and-daniel-ziga)